# How to delete an image from folder in PHP and delete file name from phpMyAdmin?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, unlink

I'm a beginner in PHP and what I need to do is delete from my uploads folder as well as deleting a row of information in the database from phpMyAdmin. I know I have to implement an unlink, but I'm not sure how to place it in my code. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
$dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'myimages');

$files = glob("uploads/*.*");

if (isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id']) ) { 

$query = "SELECT title FROM imagedata WHERE id={$_GET['id']}";

if ($r = mysqli_query($dbc, $query)) {
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($r); 

    print '<form action="delete_image.php" method="post">
    <p style="color: red;">Are you sure you want to delete this image?</p>
    <p><h4>' . $row['title'] . '</h4><br>
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="' . $_GET['id'] . '">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Delete this image"></p>
    </form>';
} else { 
    print '<p style="color: red;">Could not retrieve the image because:<br>' . mysqli_error($dbc) . '.</p><p>The query being run was: ' . $query . '</p>';
}

} elseif (isset($_POST['id']) && is_numeric($_POST['id'])) { 

$query = "DELETE FROM imagedata WHERE id={$_POST['id']} LIMIT 1";
$r = mysqli_query($dbc, $query); 

if (mysqli_affected_rows($dbc) == 1) {
    print '<p>The image has been deleted.</p>';
} else {
    print '<p style="color: red;">Could not delete the image because:<br>' . mysqli_error($dbc) . '.</p><p>The query being run was: ' . $query . '</p>';
}

} else { 
print '<p style="color: red;">This page has been accessed in error.</p>';
} 

mysqli_close($dbc);
```

Comment: enjoy getting hacked because of all your SQL injection vulnerabilities, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What column name do you use to store the file path? You will need to retrieve this as part of your first query:

`$query = "SELECT title FROM imagedata WHERE id={$_GET['id']}";`

Becomes:

`$query = "SELECT title,path FROM imagedata WHERE id={$_GET['id']}";`

And then you can use `unlink()` just above the database query:

```
unlink( $row['path'] ); // if you store full path + filename
unlink( '/path/to/your/uploads/folder/here/' . $row['path'] ); // if you store just the file name and not folder
$query = "DELETE FROM imagedata WHERE id={$_POST['id']} LIMIT 1";
$r = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
```

Comment: My columns in the phpadmin are ID, PATH, and TITLE.

Comment: Perfect, and in `PATH` does an example look like: `filename.jpg` or like: `/folder/here/filename.jpg` ? See update above using `path` column name.

Comment: It'll say "PATH - logo.png" - Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

If yo have the name of the file you could try something like

```
unlink($file);
```

This after you have removed it from your db

Then print the has been removed message